# how would I divide my background with multiple colors?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how I would divide my into different colors, I am assuming I define 3 different div tags and just change that value background. But Would this be the right way?

Comment: You can use gradients for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use gradients. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2eEGq/).

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%, #1e5799 33%, #ff3033 33%, #ff3033 66%, #f9f486 66%, #f9f486 100%);
```

Comment: thanks @BramVanroy I am assuming you can make these a lot longer correct?

Comment: What do you mean by `longer`? @bestplayer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for webkit browsers:

**CSS**

```
body{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, 
                #000000 0%, #000000 20%, 
                #FFFFFF 20%, #FFFFFF 40%, 
                #000000 40%, #000000 60%, 
                #FFFFFF  60%, #FFFFFF 80%, 
                #000000  80%, #000000  100%)";
}
```

This gradient example will look like a zebra :)

Answer (score 0):

Linear gradient is probably best response here. Another possibility is to use a narrow 1-pixel thick image strip which gets resized in the opposing dimension. Though that's more suited for a fixed display size.

Answer (score 0):

Add this class name to your HTML element
its two red color gradient but you can modify accordingly, works in almost all browsers

```
.reddishGrad{
background: #C00000; /* Old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c00000, #8B0000); /* For Safari */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#c00000, #8B0000); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#c00000, #8B0000); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#c00000, #8B0000); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take ur colors as a gradient and apply them in ur background styles. This link makes ur work easier.
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/